# Am I using the Laplace Transform pair correctly?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am given a question of Laplace Transform which is as follows:

$$   e^{t}sin2t    $$
for $$t\leq0$$

Now I know that by using the transform pair we get:

$$   [e^{-at}sin\omega_0 t]u(t) \rightarrow  \frac{\omega_0}{(s+\alpha)^2 +(\omega_0)^2}           $$

Using this pair we:

$$   [e^{t}sin2t]u(t)  \rightarrow \frac{2}{(s+1)^2 +(2)^2}         $$

Now for $u(-t)$ what I think should come is: 
$$         -\frac{2}{(s-1)^2 +(2)^2}     $$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start first at $f(t)=sin(2t)u(t)$, which has a Laplace transform of $$\frac{2}{s^2+2^2}$$ then apply time-scaling property $f(\alpha t)=\frac{1}{|\alpha|}F(\frac{s}{\alpha})$ with $a=-1$. Now, $f(t)$ becomes $sin(-2t)u(-t)$, but this is just equal to $-sin(2t)u(-t)$ because $sin(x)$ is odd function.

Lastly, apply $e^t$ to $f(t)=-sin(2t)u(-t)$, and then remove the negative.

Edit: By the way, the answer you gave is correct.